# UBUNTU 18.04 - forced logoff using settings

Tags: 18.04, settings

I did a clean install of UBUNTU 18.04 and did all the updates to current as of 02/19/20  T18:00 EST. The system is running as a VM under Hyper-V in on an HP server box.

It boots and runs fine. I logon as a user. No desktop panels open. I hit the SETTINGS Icon. The panel opens, some of the background disappears the SETTINGS panel sits idle for a few seconds and logs the user off.

I'll be glad to provide any logs or info that will help resolve the problem.

Mike

Comment: That's not a logoff. That is the desktop stack *crashing*. Look in /var/crash for the crash file that explains what went wrong.

Comment: Got it. Sure is a lot of information, but without a cheat sheet, pretty hard to tell what went askew.

Comment: I have the log file, can I post it here somehow?

Comment: Use [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) and put the link in your question above.

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/YWTjb54NPg/

Comment: Above is the log from /var/crash when the desktop crashes. Without a good deal more knowledge I cann't determine why the desktop is crashing when I hit the settings icon.